# View list of embedded fonts in PDF file with Preview

Tags: pdf, preview, embedded-fonts

In Acrobat Reader I can go to File > Properties to see all the metadata for the open PDF file: the program that created the document, author information, embedded fonts, etc.

OS X's Preview can also display metadata, albeit a more limited subset (under Tools > Show Inspector). However, you can't see embedded font information with Preview.

Is there a way in OS X (preferably with Preview, and not with Acrobat) to see what fonts are embedded in a PDF file?

Comment: You may want to see this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/614619/how-to-find-out-which-fonts-are-referenced-and-which-are-embedded-in-a-pdf-docum (answer from michelem)

Answer (score 93, accepted):

Some PDF files may include the font name in plain text within the file.

To see this, run one of these commands from the terminal or command-line.

### MacOS

```
strings /path/to/document.pdf | grep -i FontName
```

Note: MacOS might require you to install the command-line tools first.

### Windows

```
findstr FontName C:\path\to\document.pdf
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me on OSX 10.8.4; nothing matches `FontName` in the output of `strings`...

Comment: @JohnJ.Camilleri try `strings /path/to/document.pdf | grep fontname`

Comment: @James that works but only sometimes; Specifically, it doesn't seem to work with PDFs created with pdflatex.

Comment: Didn't work well for me either (on mac). On linux, pdffonts was so nice.

Comment: One other argument I would add after grep would be "-i". So the command would be: `strings /path/to/document.pdf | grep -i fontname`. This argument ignores any specific casing and catches variants such as fontName FontName fontname FontName and so on.

Comment: `strings` doesn't work for me on OS X 10.10.5 (even with the ignore case flag) - however `pdffonts` (see other answer) is perfect.

Comment: I think if the PDF is compressed then the string could be mangled beyond recognition

Comment: I want to confirm that it worked fine in macOS Sierra 10.12.6. I will suggest simplifying pdf name. I tried `strings ABC.pdf | grep FontName`

Comment: This doesn't work for me either, but [Lri's answer](https://superuser.com/a/628624/114642) does. That should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 90):

You can also use `pdffonts`, which can be installed with `brew install poppler` or `brew install xpdf`.

```
$ pdffonts file.pdf
name                                 type              encoding         emb sub uni object ID
------------------------------------ ----------------- ---------------- --- --- --- ---------
GFEDCB+MyriadSet-Medium              CID TrueType      Identity-H       yes yes yes    304  0
GFEDCB+MyriadSet-Bold                CID TrueType      Identity-H       yes yes yes    310  0
GFEDCB+MyriadSet-MediumItalic        CID TrueType      Identity-H       yes yes yes    659  0
GFEDCB+Menlo-Regular                 CID TrueType      Identity-H       yes yes yes    664  0
ZapfDingbats                         Type 1            Custom           no  no  yes    665  0
ZapfDingbats                         Type 1            Custom           no  no  yes    666  0
```

Comment: Thanks. You only need the `popper` bottle.

Comment: Also via macports "sudo port install poppler".

Comment: How does one make sense of font names such as "XSVTJR+CMSS12"?

Comment: @DavidJ.: That looks like a subset font. `CMSS12` is likely the true PostScript name of the original font, while `XSVTJR+` is added to the beginning of the name to assure this particular subset of `CMSS12` has a name that's unique to all other possible subsets. You can see this same behavior is reflected in Lri's output above (the `GFEDCB+` prefix is used for several embedded subset fonts).

Comment: On Linux, the package is usually called `poppler-utils` or `poppler_utils`.